# Is there a way to edit an svg with CSS that is being called from a different folder on my computer?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am currently stuck. In my code, I have an SVG of a map of the USA. Once a specific state is clicked, then the country fades out, and then a separate SVG of that specific state fades in. All of the 50 individual states are in a separate folder, and are being retrieved like this:

```
//On Map Click
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('path').on("click",function(e){
    var state = "counties/"+$(this).attr('id') + ".svg";
    showState(state);
  });
});

<object style="width:auto; height:auto; " id="countyLevel" data="" type="image/svg+xml">
</object>
```

Is there any way I can add CSS to the individual state SVG? For example `path:hover`?

Here is my showState() function:

```
function showState(stateFile) {
  $('.usa').fadeOut();
  $('.returncountry').fadeIn();
  $("#countyLevel").attr("data", stateFile);  
  $("#countyLevel").css('display', 'block');  
  }
```

Comment: there are lots of ways you could do it.  jquery to change the class of the object.  Defining your css in a particular way so that when the state appears it is the only tag that uses that css pathing.  etc

Comment: Well, the easiest would be to just edit the SVG itself to add the styling.

Comment: Could you show us `showState()` or explain us how you add the SVG element in the DOM?

Comment: You should consider putting your SVG directly in HTML document, without using the `object` element to embed it.

Comment: Added showState()

Answer (score 0):

You can set CSS properties to your SVG path as you would normally with other elements.

Use the properties `fill` to change the colour inside the geometry, and `stroke` to change the color of the actual line path.

Here's an example:

```css
path:hover {
  fill: red;
  stroke: blue;
}
```

```html
<svg width="190" height="160" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path d="M10 80 C 20 10, 65 0, 90 80 S 150 180, 180 80" stroke="black" fill="transparent"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Yes, i know how to do this, just having a problem because my SVG's are in another foulder